# Comparing strings C++

Tags: c++, string, compare

```
string Foo(string letter)
 {


      for (int j = 0; j < (int)alphabet.length(); j++)
     {

            if (letter[0] == (alphabet[j]));
                 return "SUCCESS";
      }

      return "FAILURE";


 }

alphabet = "Test";

cout << Foo("f") << endl;
```

This prints SUCCESS even thought it shouldn't. What's wrong with my comparison operator??

Comment: Why not just `return (letter == alphabet) ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILURE";`  or `std::string::compare` ?

Comment: @Mahesh: It's the unclear title, it's not what he's actually doing. Take a look at the code.

Comment: @Jasper I know the code has no relation to the title. OP is just comparing first character through out the iteration. I believe that is not what he wants to do at least from the title suggestion.

Comment: [`string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) anyone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (letter[0] == (alphabet[j])); // Note the semicolon at the end
```

You have an empty `if` immediately followed by `return "SUCCESS";`

Remove that semicolon:

```
if (letter[0] == alphabet[j])
    return "SUCCESS";
```

Comment: Crazy error messages and code just running but doing something different rather than telling me what's wrong aside, I do still love C++ :D

Comment: @Jasper, Eh, they can be useful. `if (setup() && goodToCallAfterSetup());` I get good uses out of this for `while` more than `if`. `while (!keyPressed ("space")); //wait for them to press space`

Comment: @chris Besides it being way too easy to misread what you are trying to do in those cases, you can do `if(setup()) goodToCallAfterSetup();` for the first, and the second you just shouldn't do (blocking/busy wait) (and it may very well not even work, as often such things are read from memory, not real time results)

Answer (score 1):

You have a semi-colon at the end of

```
 if (letter[0] == (alphabet[j]));
```

on line 10.

Unexpected semi-colon? :-)